# Error trying login and get user Context in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I setup a hyperledger composer in my aws ubuntu instance. I was able to connect to the blockchain through the playground UI as "hlfv1" connection, using the command:

```
composer-playground
```

I created a business network using the ID and enrollment secret as "admin" and "adminpw" and wrote the modelling file, script file and acl file and tested the network. Created multiple participants and issued identities to them and imported their cards to my wallet. It was working perfectly fine. But When after some time I'm trying to connect by clicking "Connect" on any of the cards in my wallet it throws the following error:

```
Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user. Error: Enrollment failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]
```

And it doesn't get connected to the business network. I have used to correct ID and secret while creating. Any solution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to restart the network, delete and reimport all card.